# dynamically replace / re-render twitter search feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have a standard twitter search feed and an input box where the user is supposed to enter a term and switch the feed to search twitter for whatever they entered. I've heard you can change embedded feeds by username by adding data attributes, but so far I don't see anyone reporting on how to do it with a search feed...

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/search?q=Christmas" data-search="Christmas" data-widget-id="12345">Tweets about Christmas</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

So far the js is pretty simple -

```
$('.twitter-timeline').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent($('#search').val())).attr('data-search', encodeURIComponent($('#search').val()));
twttr.widgets.load();
```

So you can see the idea is that it just replaces the href of the a tag and data attribute then tries to call the `load()` function on the `twttr.widgets` object. This does nothing.

Anyone know if it's possible to dynamically switch the keywords on an embedded twitter search feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

You can create widgets at run-time with factory functions (https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/creating-widgets#create-timeline). With `twttr.widgets.createTimeline` you can define a data source but this can only be one of: profile, likes, list, collection, URL (and the URL can only be one of Twitter profile, likes, list, or collection, widget configuration), widget.

So for instance this "search" by username works:

```
 twttr.widgets.createTimeline(
    sourceType: 'url',
    url: 'https://twitter.com/' + encodeURIComponent( $('#search').val())
    },
    ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/jba2uqam/

while this doesn't work:

```
twttr.widgets.createTimeline(
    {
    sourceType: 'url',
    url: 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent( $('#search').val())
    },
    ...
```

To have a customized search you need to use the API (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) that requires authentication.

Comment: Alright then. Good to know. We knew the API was an option but like a quick implementation thing was what we were looking for. Thanks